# Frequency of the Golden Bowser Train?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

Does anyone happen to know how often you can go to the Golden Bowser Train?  For those that don't yet know, it is a level with nothing but coins, and is a great way to bolster your extra lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't nailed down the *exact time* just yet, but it appears to be 3 days for the train to re-appear once you have completed it.

Answer (score 1):

The Golden Coin Express Train respawns after the player clears 25 levels.